How to make the user follow the randomize array by clicking different jbuttons?
So I'm making a food game, where I have the ingredients in Jbuttons icon and the order  to put ingredient in a randomize array. And here is the problem, what code can I use to let the user "can" only click the jbuttons in the randomize order, and once they click the wrong ingredient, there will be a try again JOptionPane?
I have no idea what code I can use to make it work, these are a part of my codes:
//array ingredients order
        String [] ingredients = {"Tomato", "Lettuce", "Egg", "Sauce", "Meat", "Onion", "Cheese", "Cucumber"};
        List<String> ingredientsList = Arrays.asList(ingredients);
        Collections.shuffle(ingredientsList);
        ingredients = ingredientsList.toArray(new String[0]);
    
        JLabel food = new JLabel(Arrays.toString(ingredients));
        food.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        food.setBounds(228, 58, 516, 48);
        contentPane.add(food);

and some of the jbuttons
JButton tomato = new JButton("");
        tomato.setOpaque(false);
        tomato.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        tomato.setBorderPainted(false);
        tomato.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                tomatoslide.setVisible(true);
                
            }
        });
        tomato.setIcon(new ImageIcon(game_food_1.class.getResource("/images/tomato.png")));
        tomato.setBounds(16, 364, 90, 90);
        contentPane.add(tomato);
        
        JButton sauce = new JButton("");
        sauce.setOpaque(false);
        sauce.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        sauce.setBorderPainted(false);
        sauce.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                sauceslide.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        sauce.setIcon(new ImageIcon(game_food_1.class.getResource("/images/sause.png")));
        sauce.setBounds(137, 364, 90, 90);
        contentPane.add(sauce);

